# Non-blocking Web Server for java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I was reading about "Tornado Web Server". 
It says that it is  non-blocking web server. 
Is there any non-blocking server for java web app ?

Comment: Its important to understand while Java Servlet Containers do support NIO it does not fix the problem of 1-thread-per-request. That is only special Comet requests will not use 1-thread-per-request. Tornado, Nodejs, Play 2.0 use a different threading model (usually with an event queue). I wrote about this here: http://adamgent.com/post/10440924094/does-java-have-an-answer-to-node-js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're thus looking for a Java servletcontainer/applicationserver which supports NIO (Non Blocking IO).

Pretty much all of them supports NIO: [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org), [JBoss AS](http://jboss.org/jbossas), [Oracle Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net), etcetera. On some of them (e.g. Apache Tomcat), you've to make some configuration changes first (see also its [HTTP connector documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) with regard to NIO). Glassfish uses under the covers [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/) as NIO implementation of the HTTP connector.

As to which one to choose, that depends on what parts provided by the huge Java EE 6 API you'd like to utilize. If it's just JSP/Servlet, then Tomcat suffices. If you need a bit more than just JSP/Servlet, the Glassfish Web Profile may suffice. If you'd like to utilize the *entire* Java EE 6 API, then go ahead with JBoss AS or Glassfish Full Platform.

Comment: Jetty is also Non blocking.

Answer (score 3):

Also there is a non-blocking library in java called [Netty](http://www.netty.io/) and you can use  Netty to write asyn network servers like web servers.

Answer (score 1):

Non-blocking sockets have been available in Java in the `java.nio` pacakges since Java 1.4.

The [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/) server is a servlet container based exclusively on NIO. Most established Java webservers are older than the NIO feature and have added support for it at some point.

Comment: `Grizzly` **isn't** a servlet container! Although there is additional `grizzly-http-servlet` module - it provides only basic `Servlet` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Besides servers that BalusC listed, there is also [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/).

Here is a nice [description of it's non-blocking operation](http://blog.igorminar.com/2009/05/grizzly-sendfile-and-comparison-of.html).